# Apache Storm: the entire job hung after 2 ~ 3 days for unknown reason

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

Recently I have submitted a storm (0.9.5) job written in Python (2.7.6) with multi-lang protocol. The Bolt class was firstly inherited from **BasicBolt** (with ack), and I have not set max.spout.pending.

```
class SnifferSpout(storm.Spout):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


class MonitorBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
    def __init__(self):
        ...


TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
      builder.setSpout("sniffer", new SnifferSpout(), 1);
      builder.setBolt("relation", new MonitorBolt(), 3).shuffleGrouping("sniffer");

conf.setDebug(false);
conf.setNumWorkers(4);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
```

It could work, however the entire job began to hung after 2~3 days.

I did not know why. And I found in the first few hours, the process latency were unbelievable (in contrast to execute latency) high.

[image]

And the process latency would increased too high (like 36456ms) sometimes

Moreover, in the log of one worker, I found

```
2015-10-31T12:14:30.784+0000 b.s.s.ShellSpout [ERROR] Halting process: ShellSpout died.
java.lang.RuntimeException: subprocess heartbeat timeout
    at backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout$SpoutHeartbeatTimerTask.run(ShellSpout.java:261) [storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
2015-10-31T12:14:30.795+0000 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: subprocess heartbeat timeout
    at backtype.storm.spout.ShellSpout$SpoutHeartbeatTimerTask.run(ShellSpout.java:261) [storm-core-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

I suspected that the issue was caused by OOM, so I checked the memory after the job hung, and found there are 3 Java processes, each consumed about 22% main memory. And the python processes only consume 1.x% memory.

I could not make sure that memory is an issue. So I tried to remove ack by using **Bolt** instead of BasicBolt together with setting **MaxSpoutPending** to 200.

And now a worse thing happened, the job consume memory very fast(the memory was dropped from 2.83G to 480M in about 10 minutes), and the executors restart every about 10 minutes due to OOM.
[image]

Anybody could help to find the root reason why this would happen

Comment: How many ackers did you configure? If you have too few, they might become a bottleneck resulting in increased processing latency.

Comment: the default configuration, one per worker, here it is 4

Comment: Can you verify that ackers are no bottleneck? You can enable system statistics in WebUI and compare tuple counts (sum tuples processed over all workers vs. sum acked tuples over all ackers).

Comment: Btw: in your initial setup you did not have set maxSpoutPending; if bolts are the bottleneck, this would also explain the increasing processing time and high memory consumption. Storm would buffer more and more tuples in input queues over time. (Why did you remove acking **and** set maxSpoutPending? This does not make sense).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I have not used anchored tuples in method **emit()** of Spout. So the ackers would ack the tuple immediately when emitting, right? And if so, the acker should not be bottleneck.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Removing acking since reliability is not necessary in this case. And for testing, I did not set max.spout.pending since the TPS  (transactions per second) < 100

Comment: If you assign no messageIDs in spouts, all anchoring and acking (in bolts) will be ignored completely. There is no reason to do any acking. Storm does not expect spout tuples without an ID to get acked. (there will be no acking from the ackers because this is just not required and/or possible.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95313/discussion-between-jacky-and-matthias-j-sax).

Comment: I am in the chat now.